# Pexpect function works randomly

Tags: python, pexpect

```
import pexpect, re

def create_group(groupname, password):
    orden = "sudo addgroup " + groupname

    child = pexpect.spawn("sudo addgroup " + nombre_grupo)
    expectation = child.expect(['password',pexpect.EOF  pexpect.TIMEOUT])

    if expectation == 0:
        child.sendline(password)  
    else:
        print("Error")

create_group("aname", "myrootpassword")
```

When I execute this function sometimes it works and most of the times it fails.
I don't get any error but always the password is sent. Why?

Comment: Change `else: "Error"` to `else: print('Error')` (or raise an exception). Otherwise there is no indication that the `else` clause was reached.

Comment: @unutbu yeah, it was an error copying the code